# Replacing ! in a string with factorial function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, eval, factorial

I am trying to build a calculator with Javscript, and have implemented all common operators. Now I would like to implement a factorial(!) operator.

I have a `factorial(n)` function defined, now I would like to replace the ! with my function and then use `eval()` on the resulting string and display the output.
I can implement it iterating backwards, but it does not work with brackets.

Here is my code -

```
function replaceFactorial(expression) {
    expression = expression.replace(' ', '');
    index = expression.indexOf('!');
    number = '';
    for (let i = index - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (!(['+', '-', '*', '/'].includes(expression.charAt(i)))) {
            number += expression.charAt(i);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(number + '!', 'factorial(' + number + ')')
    expression = expression.replace(number + '!', 'factorial(' + number + ')');
    return eval(expression);
}
```

For example: 
`factorial('5! + 5')` outputs `125`. As expected, but 
`factorial('(2 + 3)!')` does not work!

In my method, I check backwards from ! and once reaching a operator, stop and change the number. But it does not work when I have brackets.

How can I make it work?

Comment: You need a proper expression parser (which turns an expression into a list of tokens) plus a stack based evaluator, if you want to build anything decent. See [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Comment: In your "for example" section, it seems like you have the exact same input. Are you saying that it *should* output 125, but it doesn't work, or did you copy an example wrong?

Comment: @Samathingamajig The first example works, the second one does not. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Both 'examples' are the same. There is no additional brackets in either. Did you mean `factorial('(5!) + 5')` for the second-example? The conditional: `if (!(['+', '-', '*', '/'].includes(expression.charAt(i)))) {` seems to invoke `break' only for operators +, -, *, /, so why expect it to break at brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea is to define `factorial` as a prototype method of `Number`. The replacement becomes then quite trivial: every "!" can be replaced with `["factorial"]()`:

```js
"use strict"; // To avoid this-wrapping overhead (optional)

Number.prototype.factorial = function () {
    return this > 0 ? this * (this-1).factorial() : 1;
}

function evaluate(str) {
    str = str.replaceAll("!", '["factorial"]()');
    console.log(str); // Just to see what it generates
    return eval(str);
}

console.log(evaluate("1 + (2*3)!")); // 721
console.log(evaluate("3!!-1")); // 619
console.log(evaluate("(2-2)!*3")); // 3
console.log(evaluate("'abc'.length!")); // 6
```

Comment: It works like a charm!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression which looks for digits and a following bang, both grouped. Then take a function for calling `factorial` with the second argument.

```js
function factorial(n) { return +!n || n * factorial(n - 1); }

const
    string = '5! + 2!'

console.log(string.replace(/(\d+)(!)/g, (_, v) => factorial(v)));
```

Comment: Your answer does not work with brackets... `(3 + 2)! + 2!'.replace(/(\d+)(!)/g, (_, v) => factorial(v))` outputs `'(3 + 2)! + 2'`.

Comment: To other newbies out there who look at `return +!~-n || n * factorial(n-1)` and need to know what it is. This one-liner is a recursive function (to calculate the factorial of 'n', to state the obvious). (I think) The `+!~-n` ensures that the recursion stops when n reaches 0. (Other, more knowledgeable members, kindly correct).

Comment: @RandomCoder59, this should be sorted out in a step before.

Comment: Note that 0! should evaluate as 1.

Comment: `+!~-n` is a very cryptic way of saying `if (n == 1) return 1` or `+(n == 1)` (`+true //=> 1` and `+false //=> 0`) if you want to fit it as a one-liner. If you want to return `1` for both `"1!"` and `"0!"`, `+(n < 1)` is a better fit, or just `if (n < 1) return 1` if you don't mind the extra line.